# нужно найти сумму элементов главной и побочной диагоналей трёхмерного массива

Tags: c++

```
int s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j< n; ++j) {
        s += A[i][j][i];
    }
}
```

вот часть кода для нахождения суммы элементов главной диагонали трёхмерного массива. в чем ошибка? подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: очень много вопросов будет, так как вы не предоставили рабочую программу. Нужен минимальный **рабочий** пример.

Comment: По моему любые диагонали считают единичный циклом, а не двойным.

Answer (score 3):

для трехмерной матрицы это будет выглядеть как

```
int sum = 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    sum += matrix[i][i][i];
}
```

а вот побочных диагоналей, как я понимаю должно быть много?

```
sum1 += matrix[n-1-i][i][i];
sum2 += matrix[i][n-1-i][i];
sum3 += matrix[i][i][n-1-i];
```

ну и если массив одномерный (как обычно и делается), то тогда надо вычислять индекс по типу

```
const int index = i*n*n + i*n + i;
sum += matrix[index];
```